# How to query using the regexp_matches function from postgres in spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to write a query that uses the `regexp_matches` function from postgres with Spring JPA. I am totally lost on this and would like some help on how I could write this query. Any help is appreciated.

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true,
    value="SELECT (matches_regexp (t1.name, '^([\\w\\d\\-]*/)*([\\w\\d\\-]+)/?\\s*$' )) AS t1_name FROM testDb.testTable ")
List<Object> test();
```

Comment: @pcsutar any idea?

Comment: Can you please try REGEXP_MATCHES() instead of matches_regexp()?

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it does not work @pcsutar